# Prevent text from expanding shrink wrapped div

Tags: css, html, width

I have a holder div that's shrink wrapped around a couple other divs, so the holder doesn't have a set width. Also inside the holder is another div that contains text. When there's too much text it's expanding the holder so it's not shrink wrapped anymore. Here's a demo of my problem, http://jsfiddle.net/WSbAt/. This is for a photo gallery page.

I'm thinking there might not be a way without setting the width of the holder, which I can't do since the number of images per row is dynamic. I can probably figure it out with jQuery, but was hoping there's a css solution.

Edit: I'm trying not to specify any widths since the number of thumbnails per row is based on your window size.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WSbAt/

CSS:

```
#container
{
    width:600px; /*only set for demo. will be random on live page*/
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
#holder
{
    display: inline-block;
    border:2px solid blue;
}
.thumbnail
{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.expandedHolder
{
    padding:10px;
    border:2px solid yellow;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.fullImage
{
    float:left;
    width:250px;/*only set for demo. will be random on live page*/
    height:200px;
    background-color:green;
}
.text
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="holder">
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div class="expandedHolder">
            <div class="fullImage"></div>
            <div class="text">some text here. some text here. some text here. </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use the CSS max-width property?

Comment: Or the CSS overflow: hidden property?

Comment: I don't know what the max-width will be, it dependent on how many thumbnails there are per row.

Comment: what about overflow: hidden?

Comment: on which class would I use overflow?

Comment: on the .expandedHolder class

Comment: that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Sry, I guess I don't understand the question then. If you include a jsfiddle that might help us picture what you're really going for.

Comment: There is one included :) It's in the first paragraph. Maybe I should make it more noticeable.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, that's my fault, I apologize

Comment: Okay, I see now. You probably don't want to go with overflow hidden after all, because that would just hide the text. Instead you need to set a fixed width (in either percentages or pxs, but probably percentages would be better, I would imagine). This will make sure that your text word-wraps. You might want to think about using `overflow: scroll;` as well, in case the text grows taller than the element you will get scrollbars instead of it throwing it off again.

Comment: Just saw below where you state you don't want to set a width. In that case, you may need to look into using JavaScript/jQuery to dynamically control how that div operates and what it can/does contain.

Comment: I'd rather avoid specifiying widths since the width of fullImage is going to be random, but it's probably unavoidable... I'll probably be using jQuery. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In that case, you may need to look into using JavaScript/jQuery to dynamically control how that div operates and what it can/does contain.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I used jQuery to calculate what the text width should be. If anyone is curious, this is how you would fix my example.

```
var textDiv = $(".text");
textDiv.hide();//hide the text to get holder width without text

var holderWidth = $("#holder").width();
var imageWidth = $(".fullImage").width();
var textWidth = (holderWidth - imageWidth) - 45;

textDiv.css("width", textWidth + "px");
textDiv.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a percentage as width for .fullImage and .text

```
        .fullImage
        {
            float:left;
            width:70%;
            height:200px;
            background-color:green;
        }
        .text
        {
            width: auto;
            float:left;
            width:20%;
            margin-left:10px;
        }
```

Then if the text gets to large use  [text-overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

or [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

```
overflow:hidden;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RubenJonker/WSbAt/5/

Comment: Is there a way without specifying widths? I want the height of fullImage set at 200px, but I want the width set to auto since the images won't all be the same aspect ratio. Sorry I didn't explain that in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do the same, with pure CSS. I found a hacky way that works in Chrome (I haven't check other browsers yet).

```
#container {
    display: table-caption; /* Shrink the container */
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
```