# Prevent text from expanding div without JS or table-caption

Tags: html, css

My issue is solved using `display:table-caption` but that seems incorrect (since it's not actually a table caption). So my question is what is table-caption doing that solves my issue, and can that be achieved with different CSS?

**My original issue:** I have a `container` div and within that are `header`, `details`, and `footer` divs. The `header` (and less importantly `footer`) text should remain on a single line (no wrapping) and the `container` div should shrink-wrap (expand and shrink width) to fit those single line elements. However, the `details` div should NOT be allowed to expand the `container` div. Instead the `details` text should simply wrap as per whatever width the container happens to be (which would be a result of the length of the `header` and/or `footer` text).

I have found that this seems to be achievable using the `display:table-caption` style.. however this doesn't seem like an appropriate style to use (on something that isn't a table caption).

**See example:**  https://jsfiddle.net/uac032q4/1/

Note the `display: table-caption` in the `.container`'s style.

```
.container {
  display: table-caption;
  background-color: white;
}
.heading {
  font-size: 4em;
}
.details {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="heading nowrap">Strech Dont Wrap</div>
    <div class="details">
    This is the paragraph that should wrap down once it reaches the available width provided by the container box which in turn is stretched to that width by the nowrap heading text.
  </div>
  <div class="nowrap">Footer</div>
</div>
```

So, using only CSS (no JS) and without fixed widths: **is there an alternate CSS solution without using table-caption? and what is table-caption doing that is solving the wrapping issue?**

Note that there is an existing question that is essentially the same thing, however the accepted answer uses JS and the alternate answer uses `display:table-caption`:
[Prevent text from expanding shrink wrapped div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237874/prevent-text-from-expanding-shrink-wrapped-div)